# solve function resulting in list object

Tags: expression, sympy

i'm starting now to use python to sole game theory models for my research (I have never used it before). Through some guides i was able to set up variables without problem, but now I am stuck.

I have two functions, surL and surH1, both expressed through many variables (one of which is "pl")

i then use solve (surL-surH1, pl) in order to find the value of pl that makes surL=surH1, and if i print it the result is correct.

The problem is the format/type of the result:

if i do

```
plh1discr=solve (surL-surH1, pl)

print (plh1discr)
```

i get

`[k/9 + ph1 - 2*t*x + t/3]`, which is correct

but if then i do

```
double=plh1discr*2

print (double)
```

i get

```
[k/9 + ph1 - 2*t*x + t/3, k/9 + ph1 - 2*t*x + t/3]
```

So it seems like it is treating the result of solve as a string, while i would want it as an expression i can work with (i need to integrate it).
If I try to do

```
profl=integrate (plh1discr(x), (x,0,1/2))
```

I get the error "list object is not callable"
 Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The output of [`solve`](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/solvers/solvers.html#sympy.solvers.solvers.solve) is a list, as often there are multiple solutions. 
`solve(Eq(x**3 - 6*x**2 + 11*x, 6))` would be the list `[1, 2, 3]`.

If you do `* 2` with a list in Python, you get the same list twice.  `[7] * 5` is `[7, 7, 7, 7, 7]`. What you probably want, in case you're sure there is exactly one solution, is to grab the first element of the list: `plh1discr = plh1discr[0]`.

Now `plh1discr` is a sympy expression which contains some variables among which `x`. It already is a function of `x`, so you can't write `plh1discr(x)`. Just directly use the expression.

Further, note that Python will transform `1/2` to `0.5` [before sympy gets its grip on it](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/gotchas.html#python-numbers-vs-sympy-numbers). Such unnecessarily introduces float values with numeric approximation errors. This can be avoided by converting `1/2` to a symbolic sympy expression via e.g. `S(1)/2`.

```py
from sympy import symbols, S, solve, integrate

k, x, t, ph1 = symbols('k, x, t, ph1')
plh1discr = [k / 9 + ph1 - 2 * t * x + t / 3]
plh1discr = plh1discr[0]

profl = integrate(plh1discr, (x, 0, S(1) / 2))
```

Result: `k/18 + ph1/2 - t/12`

The result of `profl = integrate(plh1discr, (x, 0, 1/2))` would be much less symbolic:

`0.0555555555555556*k + 0.5*ph1 - 0.0833333333333333*t`